# How to resolve "MSOLAP.4 Provider is not registered on the local machine" error without install SQL in local machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, olap, olap-cube

If I am run OLAP application in SQL installed machine (Machine A), it will work perfectly. But I need to run that application in another machine (Machine B) with Machine A's MSOLAP DLL.

Is it possible?

If yes how can I do that?

**Update**

I have fixed this issue by using [Adomd](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6562/Cubes-MDX-Analysis-Services-and-ADOMD-in-C) connection instead of [OleDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) connection... :)

Answer (score 2):

"MSOLAP.4" is the name of the OLE DB provider for Analysis Services as included with SQL Server 2008. This driver is included with the Feature Pack for SQL Server. The SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6375). Expand the "Install instructions" header and download the correct "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services 10.0 OLE DB Provider" for your platform.

Since, typically, the latest versions can connect without problems to older versions, and SQL Server 2008 is [no longer supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/07/09/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2.aspx), I recommend installing the version from [the SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295) instead. Use "MSOLAP" as the provider name in the connection string to use the latest version rather than a specific one.